# Reference for an estimate on the sum of powers $\sum_{k=1}^4 | x_k |^{2k}$ if $\sum_{k=1}^4 | x_k |^2 =1$?

Tags: inequality, optimization

Let $(x_1, ..., x_4)$ denote the coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^4$. The unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ is identified with the set of points satisfying $x_1^2 + \cdots + x_4^2 =1$. Fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $f_k : \mathbb{S}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by the prescription $$f_k(x_1, ..., x_4) := \sum_{b=1}^4 | x_b |^{2k}.$$

> Can someone provide a reference for where an estimate on $f$ can be found?

I'm sure this is in some book on inequalities, but in the ones I've flicked through, I can't find an estimate on $\min_{x \in \mathbb{S}^3} f_k(x)$ and  $\max_{x \in \mathbb{S}^3} f_k(x)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $k > 0$ and is constant ?

Comment: @WangYeFei Ah! Thank you for pointing out the absence of clarity. Yes, $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is a fixed constant :) I've edited the post.

Comment: Lookup the [generalized means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Special_cases) inequality.

Comment: The method of Lagrange multipliers (which is standard in calculus 3 courses IIRC) shows that if your function is extremized then all nonzero coordinates must be equal (up to sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_i = x_i^2\implies \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^4 a_i = 1, 0 \le a_i \le 1\implies f(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) = a_1^k+a_2^k+a_3^k +a_4^k$.The max is $1$ when some of the $a_i = 1$ and the others are $0$. This is achieved by observing that the function is convex in each of the variables while holding the other three fixed.The min is $\dfrac{1}{4^{k-1}}$ by Jensen's inequality as the function $f(x) = x^k, k \ge 2$ is convex on $[0,1]$. If $k = 1$, the function is constant and is $1$.